# Escaping characters before converting a wildcard pattern to a regular expression

Tags: regex, qt, wildcard, qregularexpression, wildcard-expansion

The user provides a search string, and this string is dynamically converted to a regex, because the subsequent search code doesn't take a plain string but a regex as input.

I want the characters `*` and `?` to have special meanings in this user-provided string.

The current solution is to use [wildcardToRegularExpression()](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qregularexpression.html#wildcardToRegularExpression) ([Qt 5 source code](https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/text/qregularexpression.cpp.html#_ZN18QRegularExpression27wildcardToRegularExpressionE11QStringView), [Qt 6 source code](https://codebrowser.dev/qt6/qtbase/src/corelib/text/qregularexpression.cpp.html#_ZN18QRegularExpression27wildcardToRegularExpressionE11QStringView6QFlagsINS_24WildcardConversionOptionEE)):

```cpp
QRegularExpression::wildcardToRegularExpression(pattern, QRegularExpression::UnanchoredWildcardConversion);
```

The above solution works great, but it has a flaw: the `[` and `]` characters also get special meanings, which I would like to avoid.

Thus, I tried to pattern-escape the `[` and `]` before feeding the string to wildcardToRegularExpression() ([qBittorrent PR 16965](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/pull/16965), [code](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/commit/b84333f8a1d3568b3cae00f7077ad738ed79aa41)):

```cpp
// replace [ and ] with [[] and []], respectively
QString escapedPattern = pattern;
escapedPattern.replace(QRegularExpression(u"\\[|\\]"_qs), u"[\\0]"_qs);

return QRegularExpression::wildcardToRegularExpression(escapedPattern, QRegularExpression::UnanchoredWildcardConversion);
```

Sadly, this code wasn't working as expected, the search results were completely messed up, so it had to be reverted ([qBittorrent PR 17820](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/pull/17820)).

A while ago I had tried to investigate this, but just setting up the development environment had been a nightmare, and after many hours of headache I didn't succeed to complete it :\

Help would be greatly appreciated to understand and fix the issue. Here I'm aiming at Qt6, but notice there is also a Qt5 code path which had been encountering the same issue.

Comment: looks like you want to use a glob?

Comment: It seems you want to disable the special meaning of `[...]` inside glob. In this regard, I doubt there is a way to do this with the function. I think you should 1) use `QRegularExpression::escape(glob_pattern)` and then `.replace("\\?", ".")` and then `.replace("\\*", ".*")`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew actually, looks like substituting `[` with `[[]` before calling should work (so perhaps the substitution in the question is being done incorrectly). note that the function treats `/` ( "\\" on windows) specially